# Which FB SDK version should I use with iOS 5?

Tags: facebook, ios5, version

My project uses iOS 5.1 + Xcode 4.5 in this version. All I really want to do right now is to read a wall w posts from Facebook (see below link). And I will not be using iOS 6 for now.

Before beginning with Facebook SDK I need to know a couple of things;

1. Which version of FB SDK should I use together with iOS 5.1?
2. Does the latest FB SDK "downgrade gracefully" when used with iOS
   5.1?
3. Any good examples of the basics to get started to read FB content? (Exept the FB Dev examples)

See also: [Just want to read a Facebook wall, do I need to install FB SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702754/just-want-to-read-a-facebook-wall-do-i-need-to-install-fb-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

use facebook sdk 3.1 or > 3.1. Because FBconnect is not working in latest build (ios5 or above)

try this [FB here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/downloads)

Comment: Thank's but maybe the reason it's not working for you is found here:  http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12610078/facebook-sdk-3-1-for-ios-runs-on-ios6-but-crashes-on-ios-5-x